# Is it possible onKeypress have more than 1 event within one input box?

Tags: html, onkeypress

This is what I tried, but it's not working.

```
<input type="text" name="name" onKeypress="return noComma(event);return handler_address(event);">
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible - think about it, after the first function returns the 2nd function won't run - that's the whole point of a return statement, to return a value and control to the calling process.

It isn't really clear what you are trying to do, but I would suggest writing a single function that wraps the other two.

```
<input type="text" name="name" onKeypress="return wrapped(event);">

function wrapped(event) {
   noComma(event);
   return handler_address(event);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jason, thanks for the explaination and solution. It's working.